# Slow Flask on mod_wsgi on openshift

Tags: python, flask, mod-wsgi, openshift

I have some performance issues with my Flask application on openshift.
There is a need to get some images from database and display them on the web page. And
for this taks, I have created a simple method :

```
@app.route('/getImage/')
def getImageFromUrl(url=None):
    return make_response(getImageFromDb(request.args['url']));
```

There are maximum 10 images per page. And the problem is that this is slow.... veerry slow.
On my local machine, started with app.run() (even in debug mode) it is super fast, so I asume there is something in mod_wsgi.
Also there are these error messages in log files:

```
Exception KeyError: KeyError(140116433057760,) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib64/python2.6/threading.pyc'> ignored
```

and

```
 [error] server reached MaxClients setting, consider raising the MaxClients setting
```

What is happening and what should I do to speed the things up?

Answer (score 0):

`Exception KeyError` is caused by gevent I guess, should be more code in question :) To avoid it import `gevent` before all.
`server reached MaxClients setting` seems to be Apache error and should be investigated with logs and settings MaxClients and ServerLimt.

Answer (score 0):

The KeyError is usually because you are using an old version of mod_wsgi. Use mod_wsgi 3.3 or later, which has changes to accommodate the changes which were made in Python that caused this.

Comment: Unfortunately i can not update mod_wsgi. I am using OpenShift, so it comes already configured. It seems I have to wait for an update.